# Images not resized based on Bootstrap column size

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to display 4 images per row. Code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img src="{site_url}images/products/4906_1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img src="{site_url}images/products/4906_1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img src="{site_url}images/products/4906_1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="{site_url}scents/baobab/pearls/black-pearls"><img src="{site_url}images/products/4906_1.jpg"></a>
    </div>                                                                                    
</div>
```

And I expect too see images resized based on column style from Bootstrap, but what I'm getting are overlapping full images .

Any clue what is going on?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Update:** As an alternative (as pointed out in this answer's comments by @JasonAller), you could add `class="img-responsive"` to each `img` element. This applies `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element. See the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) for more info.

## update for bootstrap v4

The classname for bootstrap v4 is `img-fluid`
[Bootstrap v4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/)

Comment: What is the benefit of adding that over using `class="img-responsive"` on the `<img>` elements?

Comment: No added benefit aside from less markup. Adding an `img-responsive` class would work also you'd just have to remember to do it for every image.

Comment: maybe you should try max-width instead so images don't stretch.

Comment: class="img-responsive" did it for me. I also had to add   style="padding:0"  to the containing div, as Katia Punter suggests below, to get a good result that wasn't too small.

Answer (score 27):

With Bootstrap 4 you must use use class="img-fluid", class="img-responsive" will work in 3.x.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes on dynamic content when you have no control over what users put in, class="img-responsive" would not work. And 'width: 100%' for each image is tricky as well. So I am using:

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Beware that bootstrap columns have padding as well; that may be unexpected.

The following:

```
div class="col-sm-6" style="padding:0"
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

General solution for Bootstrap 5. And I'm adding a particular solution to OP's problem at the end of my answer.

Resizing seems not to be an easy task on some situations. I haven't found any built-in implementation in BS5 for specific image resizing using Bootstrap classes.

The best solution I've found is handling images as they were any other HTML element (a `span` or a `div` element).

## GENERAL SOLUTION

### Use this snippet

```html
<img
    src="~/Content/images/YourImage.jpg"
    class="img-fluid mx-auto mx-lg-0 h-100 col-8 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1 my-auto"
>
```

NOTE: This is just a general example. Adapt it to your needs.

### Explanation (more or less this is what happens)

1. BASIC SET UP (for Bootstrap responsive image):

   - `img-fluid`: Image is made responsive. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales with the parent width.
   - `mx-auto`: centers the image in the horizontal axis, for phone views. Left and right margins are set to auto
   - `mx-lg-0`: When the lg break-point is reached, the margin to both sides are set to 0.
2. USING COLUMNS (resize to your needs):

   - `h-100`: Image height is set to 100% relative to the parent. This should preserve the correct aspect ratio.
   - `col-8`: At the smallest screen size, image will occupy 8 columns.
   - `col-sm-6`: After the small screen break point (see links at the section below), image will occupy 6 columns.
   - `col-md-4`: At mid sized screens, 4 columns.
   - `col-lg-1`: At large sized screens, 1 column.
   - `my-auto`: This is for vertical centering (optional).

Remember, you'll set the columns occupied at your own will and pleasure.

### Result

[image: Alligator]

## SOLUTION FOR THIS QUESTION

The main problem with your code is that you're missing classes. Remember: Bootstrap is mostly about using classes correctly. You should think twice if you're using the built-in classes correctly before putting in your own CSS code.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex gap-2">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tm1bGx3.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto mx-lg-0 h-100 col-3 my-auto">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tm1bGx3.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto mx-lg-0 h-100 col-3 my-auto">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tm1bGx3.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto mx-lg-0 h-100 col-3 my-auto">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tm1bGx3.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto mx-lg-0 h-100 col-3 my-auto">
</div>
```

For responsiveness on different screen sizes, take a look to the general solution above.

## Links

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/images/#responsive-images
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use the width tag in the html element, for example:

```
    <img width="60%" src="...">
```

I find it more useful, since you can play with the percentage until you have the desired size.

Comment: This isn't a very responsive solution. Considering Bootstrap is a responsive framework.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to use the `<picture>` and the `<source>` tags. Just make sure you have different sizes of your image prepared for various screens.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_media.asp

Comment: Not entirely relevant to the question since it specified use of bootstrap, but could be used in some scenarios.